# gtar recursively untar but leave in top directory

Tags: scripting, tar, solaris

I am trying to recursively untar a whole lot of directories that have .tar files in them, but without creating any new subdirectories.

I am successfully able to do one at a time with this command

```
gtar -xf *.tar --strip-components 2
```

However, I have to BE IN the subdirectory in order for that to work, and I want to do it en masse from the directory above.

Here is my directory structure:

```
/top_directory
   /sub1
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub2
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub3
      tarfile1.tar
   /sub4
      tarfile1.tar
```

So I can't just move them all up a directory and then untar them either, because they are all called `tarfile1.tar`, so they need to remain in their subdirectories.

However, I don't want them to create any MORE subdirectories; I just want the files that they contain.

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
/top_directory
       /sub1
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
          file3.txt
       /sub2
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
       /sub3
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
          file3.txt
       /sub4
          tarfile1.tar
          file1.txt
          file2.txt
```

I think I've gotten close with this command:

```
for file in *; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

but it returns this error:
gtar: This does not look like a tar archive

and when I try

```
for file in *.tar; do gtar -xf ${file} --strip-components 2; done
```

I get the same error.

How can I accomplish untarring all the files in the subdirectories, while keeping the untarred files IN those directories?

I'm on Solaris11.